# Any way in visual studio to programmatically modify selected editor text while in editor? Code snippets? Macros?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, macros, code-snippets

I would like to be able to highlight a section of text and remove any ';' in the highlighted section.

I've written a "surround with snippet" to encapsulate the highlighted text, but would also like to pragmatically modify that text and am unsure how.

I use the "Snippet Designer" extension in visual studios for snippet creation.

I would expect the highlighted text `" RunMethod1(var1); "` to be converted to 
`".Then(() => RunMethod1(var1) ) "` ie without the semi-colon.

Comment: You could look into the Roslyn extensibility features of VS.

Comment: Sounds like a good subject for some research...

Comment: You could use an AutoHotKey script to cut,replace,paste (if extending VS turns out too much work)

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. It was very helpful. For now I'm going the AutoHotkey rout. I'd never heard of the tool before and have spent a bit of time already today playing with it. Quite handy. Thanks again everyone for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command for [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) to remove any ';' in the selection and surround it with 'Then' (Language: C#):

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
    {
        EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
        ts.Text = ".Then(() =>" + ts.Text.Replace(";", "") + ") ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotKey was able to do what I needed and proved to be a pretty robust tool after getting a hang of the syntax. Thanks for the suggestion Caius Jard.

This was the code I used to solve the problem.

> #p::           ;Hold 'WindowsKey' and press 'P'
>    ConvertToPromise()
>
> return
>
> ;------------------------------------------------
>    ConvertToPromise()
>    {
>
> oCB := clipboard    ; local var to save original clipboard content
>     clipboard :=
>     send, ^c
>     ClipWait,1
>     nCB := clipboard    ; get currently Selected text.
>     mnCB := EraseSemiColon(nCB)
>
> clipboard := mnCB
>     send, .Then(()=> ^v )
>     sleep, 100
>     clipboard := oCB    ; restores original Clipboard value.
>
> }
>
> ;-------------------------------------------------
>    EraseSemiColon(stringText)
>      {
>      strVar := stringText
>      modifiedSt :=
>      StrReplace(strVar, "`;", "")
>
> return, %modifiedSt%
>      }