# In Visual Studio, would there be way to paste the clipboard text with modification?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio, would there be way to paste the clipboard text with modification?

Basically I want to perform regex replacement `(.*)` and `$1` kind of behavior without regex replacement.

For example, I would like to highlight text `xxxx` and replace it with `/* obsolete xxxx */`.

Pasting `/* obsolete */` is not what I want to do because it is lacking `xxxx`

I cannot use regex listed above because I want to highlight any kind of word in the code.

Comment: It is unclear why the clipboard needs to be involved.  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194009/how-do-you-reference-a-capture-group-with-regex-find-and-replace-in-visual-studi).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53966998/any-way-in-visual-studio-to-programmatically-modify-selected-editor-text-while-i